# How to get only remote git operations to trigger a ssh-add event for ssh-agent?

Tags: git, bash, ubuntu, ssh-keys, ssh-agent

I recently asked a [question on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36255/why-wont-ssh-agent-save-my-unencrypted-key-for-later-use) about getting ssh-agent to automatically save my passphrase protected key for later re-use without having to re-enter the passphrase during bash login (non-GUI/Gnome). I got a nice bash script in response, but unfortunately it is triggered to ask for the passphrase no matter the git operation. I only want to be prompted if they key is not already in ssh-agent and a remote git operation is being performed.

This is due to the fact that I use `$(__git_ps1 "[%s]")` in my bash prompt to display the git branch of the current working directory (`pwd`). So when I ssh into the machine it immediately asks me for the keys passphrase before it can render the bash prompt!

The current script from [the answer to my question on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36255/why-wont-ssh-agent-save-my-unencrypted-key-for-later-use/36302#36302) looks like:

In `~/.bash_profile`:

```
# File: ~/.bash_profile

# source ~/.profile, if available
if [[ -r ~/.profile ]]; then
  . ~/.profile
fi

# start agent and set environment variables, if needed
agent_started=0
if ! env | grep -q SSH_AGENT_PID >/dev/null; then
  echo "Starting ssh agent"
  eval $(ssh-agent -s)
  agent_started=1
fi

# ssh become a function, adding identity to agent when needed
ssh() {
  if ! ssh-add -l >/dev/null 2>-; then
    ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_dsa
  fi
  /usr/bin/ssh "$@"
}
export -f ssh

# another example: git
git() {
  if ! ssh-add -l >/dev/null 2>-; then
    ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_dsa
  fi
  /usr/bin/git "$@"
}
export -f git
```

So as you can see the git function is triggered on every git operation.

I had thought that git would use `ssh` to make the connection, but it doesn't appear to trigger the `ssh()` function in the above script. How does git perform its ssh operations? Does it access /usr/bin/ssh directly rather than relying on the bash path?

Have you got a better way of doing this or a nice workaround for the current script?

Comment: The git executable /usr/bin/git is not written in bash (AFAIK) and so there is no reason for it to execute your ssh function.

Comment: @nhed that was my hypothesis. I wonder if I can replace `/usr/bin/ssh` with a bash `ssh` wrapper script so that it would be triggered?

Comment: sounds dangerous, the git man-page mentions an env variable GIT_SSH - make that point to a wrapper - that may work cleaner.  Give that a shot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use agent forwarding even if you ssh into multiple hosts recursively. When ssh asks for a key for the first time, your local agent runs `$SSH_ASKPASS` and forwards the unlocked key to the host. Note that you have to enable agent forwarding (see [man 5 ssh_config](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ssh_config%205)).

In ~/.ssh/config enable forwarding for each individual host you require:

```
Host example.org
    ForwardAgent yes
```

On the server side agent forwarding is enabled by default.

If you do not want to use agent forwarding for some reason, then I think overriding the ssh command is your only option.

Comment: I had forgotten about `AgentForwarding`. Good call and it fits my particular work flow perfectly.

Answer (score -2):

I would not recommend a pass phrase in your key. Things like gitolite will not act well with it. Consider using a new key with no pass phrase.

My $0.02

Comment: I don't use gitolite so I don't see that being a problem. I am not trusting enough to have an unprotected key sitting on my disk and I would never have one except for a really locked down account for automated processes. I don't understand how a passphrase would affect git though as it is all dealt with at the ssh layer and not in git itself.